# HTML, to compile or not to compile... externally?

Tags: javascript, json, compilation

This is not particularly a problematic programming query, as it is instead a best practise question.

When I write JavaScript, sometimes I make ajax requests, whether it be simple true/false request or some JSON. However, ocassionally, I am required to compile HTML so that, if for instance, the JavaScript were to load data for a page, it would compile data through JSON. Yet, I am having some mind-philosophasterings to whether I should maybe compile the HTML prehand, within my PHP? That way I can just dump the HTML on to the page, without making the JavaScript over heat itself.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a massive number of DOM nodes to manipulate, I suggest you use ajax to move data and use JavaScript to work with the DOM.  JavaScript will not overheat :)

I have used simple techniques like having a hidden template in the HTML that I copy (eg, using jQuery), update, and insert into the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I usually return the data instead of preformated HTML. It saves bandwidth, it lets me format the data the way I need on that page and I can change the layout without touching the code that generates the data, I can reuse the data on another page and format it differently. (it also makes it easier for others to (ab)use your data)